# How to include a python .egg library that is in a subdirectory (relative location)?

Tags: python, egg

How do you import python .egg files that are stored in a relative location to the .py code?

For example,

```
My Application/
My Application/library1.egg
My Application/libs/library2.egg
My Application/test.py
```

How do you import and use library1 and library2 from within test.py, while leaving the .egg libraries in-place?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An .egg is just a .zip file that acts like a directory from which you can import stuff.

You can use the `PYTHONPATH` variable to add the `.egg` to your path, or append a directory to 
`sys.path`. Another option is to use a `.pth` file pointing to the eggs.

For more info see [A Small Introduction to Python eggs](http://mrtopf.de/blog/python_zope/a-small-introduction-to-python-eggs/), [Python Eggs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs) and [All about eggs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cppeak3/index.html).

For example, if your `library1.egg` contains a package named `foo`, and you add `library1.egg` to `PYTHONPATH`, you can simply `import foo`

If you can't set `PYTHONPATH`, you can write:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("library1.egg")
import foo
```

Comment: So:
    import sys
    sys.path.append("library1.egg")
    import foo

Comment: hi, How can I load the module/library contained in egg dynamically and instantiate the class?

Answer (score 2):

You can include each egg on the sys.path, or create a .pth file that mentions each egg.

If you have many eggs that you need in your system I'd recommend using something like buildout, that will make the setup easily replicatable. It will handle the eggs for you.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/