# Python share a module without installation

Tags: python

I want to use a external module (psutil) which is having some C code and python code. On my local machine, I have installed this module using Mingw. Now, I want to use this library on other machines (without installing it on each machine). So can I copy my compiled code to a common location and then from other machines, I include it in `sys.path` and should be able to use it?

I have been searching for a right way to use a library without having to install it on each machine, so far I found to use `bdist` option, but that creates a zip file and I assume it needs to unextracted on each machines.

Can some one please help me on what should be best approach to be followed. I know, I could use Pyinstaller, Py2exe but my other machines are having python and I just want to use this module without having to install it everywhere.

Comment: Can you bundle it in the same source tree as your own code?

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success with this using [eggs](http://mrtopf.de/blog/en/a-small-introduction-to-python-eggs/). You can create eggs of all your additional modules, put them in some directory, and then simply add that directory to your `sys.path` and then import the egg. Since you have a C extension there, [you probably need to use](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs) the [pkg_resources module](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html).

This is neat in that it creates good separation and encapsulation of the other code.

A bit more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1108384/709852).

Answer (score 0):

Use `bdist` with the correct options:
*From the docs:*

```
The available formats for built distributions are:

Format      Description                  Notes
gztar       gzipped tar file (.tar.gz)   (1),(3)
ztar        compressed tar file (.tar.Z) (3)
tar         tar file (.tar)              (3)
zip         zip file (.zip)              (2),(4)
rpm         RPM                          (5)
pkgtool     Solaris pkgtool  
sdux        HP-UX swinstall  
wininst     self-extracting ZIP file for Windows (4)
msi         Microsoft Installer.

Notes:
1. default on Unix
2. default on Windows
3. requires external utilities: tar and possibly one of gzip, bzip2, or compress
4. requires either external zip utility or zipfile module (part of the standard Python library since Python 1.6)
5. requires external rpm utility, version 3.0.4 or better (use rpm --version to find out which version you have)
```